# Typescript enum map return lookup function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I have a function that maps a lookup class into a usable array for my React project. I was able to get the function to work, but right now it is looping through the enum twice and returning undefined for the first iteration.

This works but is returning 8 elements, 4 undefined then 4 correct objects. Why is it looping twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably looping twice (re-renders) due to some side-effect that happens inside your component. Could you please provide a React Component where this is used?

Also, I advise you not to use Class Static Members at all and use something like this:

```
export const CustomerSupportTiles: Record<
  CustomerSupportType,
  CustomerSupportTileModel
> = {
  [CustomerSupportType.Account]: {
    title: 'Account',
    iconClass: 'fa-user',
    link: AppRoutes[RouteName.CustomerSupport], //change when route is added
  },
  [CustomerSupportType.Finances]: {
    title: 'Finances',
    iconClass: 'fa-file-invoice-dollar',
    link: AppRoutes[RouteName.CustomerSupport], //change when route is added
  },
  [CustomerSupportType.Ordering]: {
    title: 'Ordering',
    iconClass: 'fa-shopping-cart',
    link: AppRoutes[RouteName.CustomerSupport], //change when route is added
  },
  [CustomerSupportType.ListManagement]: {
    title: 'List Management',
    iconClass: 'fa-list-alt',
    link: AppRoutes[RouteName.CustomerSupport], //change when route is added
  },
};
```

Note the `Record` utility type for a cleaner type description. And for the helper function:

```
export const getCustomerSupportTiles = (): CustomerSupportTileModel[] =>
  (Object.keys(CustomerSupportType) as Array<keyof typeof CustomerSupportType>).map(
    (key: keyof typeof CustomerSupportType) => {
      return CustomerSupportTiles[CustomerSupportType[key]];
    }
  );
```

or just iterating over the `CustomerSupportTiles` object items could work.

Another possible approach is to use the `Object.values(CustomerSupportTiles)` to return all values from that object.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript generates enum objects with both keys and values.

```
console.log(CustomerSupportType);
```

Will yield:

```
{
  0: "Ordering"
  1: "Finances"
  2: "Account"
  3: "ListManagement"
  Ordering: 0
  Finances: 1
  Account: 2
  ListManagement: 3
}
```

And as you don't have keys for 0, 1, 2 and 3 in `CustomerSupportTiles`, it results in `undefined`.
As a solution, you could filter the keys for non numbers:

```
(Object.keys(CustomerSupportType) as Array<keyof typeof CustomerSupportType>)
    .filter(key => isNaN(Number(key))) // <--
    .map(
      (key: keyof typeof CustomerSupportType) => {
        return CustomerSupportTilesLookup.CustomerSupportTiles[CustomerSupportType[key]];
      }
    );
```